# Request.ParseMultipartForm leaks memory

Tags: http, go, memory-leaks, server, multipart

I am writing a Go server which handles image uploading via Multipart Requests, but after a while i get really bad memory usages (up to 100% RAM).

I am using the basic http.ListenAndServeTLS and http.HandleFunc to do so.
Below a snippet of my code and the svg i got from pprof after a lot of image uploads.

```
func HandleUploadImage(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    defer func() {
        // Release mem
        if req != nil {
            fmt.Println("Releasing request")
            if req.MultipartForm != nil {
                fmt.Println("Releasing MultipartForm")
                req.MultipartForm.RemoveAll()
            }
            if req.Body != nil {
                fmt.Println("Closing req.Body")
                req.Body.Close()
            }
        }

    }()

    // parse request
    const _2MB = 1 << 20
    if err := req.ParseMultipartForm(_2MB); nil != err {
        u.Log("Error", "Couldn't parse MultiPartForm", map[string]interface{}{"Error": err}, u.GetFile_line(), "")
        return
    }

    id := req.FormValue(formValueString)

    // get the json data
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(id), marshalStruct); nil != err {
        u.Log("Error", "Couldn't Unmarshal JSON", map[string]interface{}{"Error": err}, u.GetFile_line(), "")
        return
    }

    // Do something with the image and save it

    // Marshal the reponse to JSON.
    resJSON, err := response.ToJSON()
    if err != nil {
        u.Log("Error", "Couldn't create JSON from response struct", map[string]interface{}{"Error": err, "ResponseStruct": response}, u.GetFile_line(), username)
        return
    }
}
```

[pprof_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDPBr.png)

Comment: Your "Release mem" function doesn't do anything. You can't explicitly release memory, and you don't need to close the Body on http requests. The usual cause of a "leak" in Go is goroutines that haven't returned, so start by looking at a full stack trace.

Comment: `pprof` can be a *huge* help with detecting memory hogs and goroutine leaks.

Comment: @JimB but you can force Go to do GC sooner with debug.FreeOSMemory(). I use it in some of my apps which parse large amounts of large files when I need more memory for the OS as soon as possible.

Comment: @geek1011: FreeOSMemory forces a GC cycle (which means less and less with an increasingly concurrent GC) and "advises" the OS is it can reclaim some of the memory. There is no guarantee the OS will actually mark it as free or use it again, especially if there is no memory pressure on the system. There is rarely any real use to calling that, other than for debugging, since the scavenger will attempt to free memory eventually anyway.

Comment: @JimB I use it myself and it works fine, and the OP says that it uses 100% RAM, which means the system most likely try to reclaim it if it can.

Comment: @geek1011: regardless, `FreeOSMemory` shouldn't not be relied on to do anything. If you've reached 100% memory usage, you have other problems besides freeing "unused" memory. The GC is always running, and the `gctrace` output or runtime memstats would show how much memory could theoretically be freed anyway.

Comment: @JimB I agree with your first and third points. For the second one, the GC tries to spread up the freeing over a longer period of time, and it can be useful to force GC if you know there is a lot to collect. 

An example is an indexer. If you are indexing a lot of large files, and are finished, it can be quite beneficial to force GC.

Comment: @sen-petersven what is `// Do something with the image and save it`? That might be the problem.

Comment: @sen-petersven  any fix for this? got same issue with req.ParseMultipartForm() and doing NOTHING else.